# Why is my Mac randomly mixing up my typing?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, pages

Big Sur (OS11.5.2) 8 GB RAM When I type there is hesitation, either brief or totally tying up the computer, and the words are garbled, letters and half-sentences repeated, and generally unreadable.  Certainly happens in Pages and Safari.  Seems worse in Safe Mode.
The "foress wiresrd" (wireless keyboard) battery is at 98%. I have toggled the keyboard on and off several times.
I can achieve very little productivity.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? - Preferably try with a wired keyboard. If that works, you know where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks.  This computer has been so full of problems that I cannot remember if I have used a wired keyboard.    I will be embarrassed if the answer turns out to be so simple!

Comment: If the keyboard has removable batteries, take them out, wait a few minutes, and re-pair. Also: any new (I assume Bluetooth) wireless accessory devices in the vicinity?